# Need help - Haskell Replace

Tags: string, list, haskell, replace

I need to change one string from a list of strings (chars if a string is just one letter) for another one from the other list.  The signature looks like this:

```
replace :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String
```

and I should use functions `words`/`unwords`. for e.g. I have `[("train","Car")]` "John got hit by train."  and if I run it the result has to be  "John got hit by car.". You see the "train" string was replaced for the "car" one.

I tried everything but I couldn't figure it out.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: You tried everything? How about showing us your attempts, so we know how to help you best?

Comment: because i always deleted the code, why should have i keep it if it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the other provided solutions are more idiomatic. Since it sounds like you're being taught and need to structure it this way, here's an example using `words`/`unwords` and explicit recursion:

```
replace :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String
replace a b = unwords $ foldl inner (words b) a
    where inner ls tup = replace' tup ls

replace' :: (String, String) -> [String] -> [String]
replace' tup (x:xs)
    | x == fst tup = snd tup : replace' tup xs
    | otherwise    = x : replace' tup xs
replace' _ [] = []
```

This `words` approach breaks when you use punctuation, but it works for simple examples:

```
*Main> replace [("train", "car"), ("dog", "cat")] "dog cannot drive a train"
"cat cannot drive a car"
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try it tommorow and i'll give you a feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `map change` to apply the `change` function to each string.

`lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b` checks a list of pairs for a matching `a` and gives you `Just b` if it found one and `Nothing` otherwise. Let's check the output of `lookup oldString changeList` and replace the `Nothing`s with the `oldString` if we get it, but use a `newString` if we get one:

```
replace changeList input = map change input where 
   change oldString = case lookup oldString changeList of
       Just newString -> newString
       Nothing -> oldString
```

Comment: no i cant use Lookup .. just replace with a code ... and words/unwords

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand your question, but you might want

```
replace xs w w' = map (\(a,b) -> (a,if b == w then w' else b)) xs
```

For example: `replace [(1,2), (3,2), (5,4)] 2 0` => `[(1,0), (3,0), (5,4)]`. This function generalizes, and should work on strings.

Comment: no, you just did the oposite and it's not even connecting two lists :/ I give you an example:

replace :: [(String, String)] -> String -> String

 *here goes the code I need*

and then in WINHUGS, you call for replace:

Main> replace [("fox", "cat")] "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

and the result will be:
"The quick brown cat jumps over the lazy dog"